# Как отправить данные формы на сервер?

Tags: php, html, laravel, form, форма

Подскажите, как  отправлять данные из html(bootstrap) формы на сервер.**PHP?Laravel?Js?**

По **PHP** и **JS** знаю самую самую базу,но сайт надо делать.

*Напишите,пожалуйста пример.
Научите чайника,заранее спасибо.*

Comment: https://tryphp.w3schools.com/showphp.php?filename=demo_form_validation_complete пример формы

Comment: сервер на js: https://expressjs.com/ru

Comment: https://sozdatisite.ru/php/sozdanie-formy-registratsii-i-avtorizatsii-v-php.html Здесь можно скачать архив, но самому добавить файл под названием: dbconnect.php и правильно его заполнить следуя описанию из статьи. Также там в архиве уже есть файл sql. Всё это делается за 5-7 мин, и у тебя готовая форма) Удачи!

Comment: @O K, sozdatisite.ru... безопасность дырявая

Comment: Есть сравнение-пример разных frontend/backend решений https://github.com/gothinkster/realworld -- для общей картины

Answer (score 1):

Для начала тебе нужно в самой форме задать метод через который ты будешь передавать данные, в нашем случае это будет POST, так же еще есть GET но он имеет некое количество отличий например: не можете передать большое количество данных.

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Эл. почта"> 
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

И так, мы создали форму. Обязательно задай имя для поля с помощью атрибута name="" которое хочешь передать, это нам потребуется для того чтобы определить ее в суперглобальной переменной $_POST в которую будем передавать данные.

Приступим к написанию php кода.

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['email']; // В аргумент суперглобальной переменной вводим имя поля данные которого мы хотим получить
?>
```

Чуть не забыл, не забывай фильтровать входящие на сервер данные с помощью htmlspecialchars() или htmlentities() чтобы обезопасить себя от xss(межсайтового скриптинга).

Comment: исправил: 1) смысл POST, что он для изменений, 2) htmlentities не обязаны быть на входе, и не защищают полностью от взлома

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov зачем вообще их юзать, если можно просто переменную жестко через `preg_replace` прогнать при получении и всяких "Левых" не предусмотренных символов - как не бывало. Или есть минус ?

Comment: @CryEngine V - FlowGraph, ввели название фирмы "Procter & Gamble", вполне разрешенное. Его можно хранить в базе, как: 1) "Procter & Gamble" или 2) "Procter &amp; Gamble". (1) удобно, если у нас много форматов (обмен json, pdf и т. д.). (2) удобно, если у нас везде формируется сразу хтмл, и однажды введенное во многих местах выводится.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov ну, а можно просто вместо & написать And. Многие даже и не вкуривают, что значит амперсант

Comment: @CryEngine V - FlowGraph, это уже заказчик решает, как у него фирма называется

Comment: @CryEngine V - FlowGraph, молчаливую замену я бы не делал; потом ищи где что пропало, пройдя через кучу мест. Если что запрещено -- кидаем ошибку, показываем пользователю, ждем пока исправит.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Зачем ты правил да еще и с ошибками, советую подробнее почитать про POST и GET методы.

htmlspecialchars() и htmlentities() одинаковые фильтры единственное их отличие в том что htmlentities преобразует все допустимые символы в соответствующие html сущности, и при отправки данные с формы на сервер их желательно применять, а sql-инъекция и xss атака вообще два разных понятия.

Comment: @beaxs, 1) какие ошибки? 2) html**s() преобразуют текст в хтмл; когда их запускать в документации php не рекомендовано; где тогда это рекомендовано? Если я буду хтмл делать реактом, и слать с сервера json, они мне вообще не понадобятся. 3) sql-инъекция и xss вообще два разных понятия, как я и написал.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Где ты прочитал что htmlspecialchars() преобразует текст в html, здесь как раз таки наоборот

Comment: @beaxs, https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php `htmlspecialchars — Преобразует специальные символы в HTML-сущности`

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Ну да, при фильтрации строки с помощью htmlspecialchars() - HTML код не будет выполняться. Скорее всего просто ты не так это понимаешь

Comment: @beaxs, я понимаю так, как написано в документации. А тебе объяснили упрощенно. И я даже понимаю почему тебе советовали использовать ее для "фильтрации" на входе. Так было легче объяснить. Было 2 варианта: рассказать тебе не совсем правильно, но с позитивным эффектом, или рассказать непонятно. В реальности надо смотреть архитектуру конкретного приложения. Если есть источники, где "фильтрацию" обосновывают, можешь поделиться.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Мне никто этого не советовал, это сугубо мое мнение. Возьмём в пример мессенджер и отправим сообщение <button>Button</button>, без фильтрации такая строка выполниться и выведется кнопка, это и есть межсайтовый скриптинг

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov не нужно вносить такие существенные правки в чужие ответы. В таком случае лучше свой ответ дать.

Comment: @Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik, хорошо, добавил свой ответ

Comment: @beaxs, добавил свой ответ, пожалуйста ознакомься; если заметишь нестыковки -- пиши; просто хочется донести мысль; у меня, кстати, сугубо мое мнение некоторое время назад совпадало с сугубо твоим.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov отлично)

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov

$string = 'трактор "Беларусь"';
echo htmlspecialchars($string);

Output: трактор "Беларусь"

Comment: @beaxs, ты смотришь "Output" браузером; добавил пример в ответ

Comment: @beaxs, браузер получает html с `&quot;`, парсит, и в DOM у него уже `"`; за тем оно и делалось.

Answer (score 1):

Это вариант ответа @beaxs, в котором я постарался дать более широкий взгляд на некоторые вещи.

Форма в HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Эл. почта"> 
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

У формы выбран метод POST, т. к. мы выполняем действие-изменение -- пишем данные в базу (еще есть GET, используемый для запроса данных).

`name="email"` -- это имя, под которым данные будут доступны при обработке POST-а на сервере.

Например в PHP -- `$_POST['email']`

Необходимо учесть 2 момента, связанных с безопасностью:

1. SQL injection -- взлом сервера
2. xss -- межсайтовый скриптинг

---

Нельзя вклеивать в SQL запрос данные полученные с клиента.
Чтобы обезопасить от взлома сервера (SQL injection) необходимо использовать подготовленные выражения (prepare-bind-execute):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));
```

---

Теперь про xss:

Представим, что не хакер, а обычный человек ввел в инпут `трактор "Беларусь"`. Мы это отправили POST-ом и сохранили в базу. Потом Вытащили и вставили обратно в HTML инпут с помощью `echo`.

И на экране человек увидит просто `трактор` , т. к. `<input value="трактор "Беларусь"">` сломано из-за кавычек, и надо было сделать `<input value="трактор &quot;Беларусь&quot;">` -- ***преобразование текста в html*** (`htmlspecialchars`).

Варианты решения:

1. делать преобразование сразу, как получили POST
2. делать преобразование в момент echo в html
3. не делать echo в html, а использовать **шаблонизатор**, json и т. п.

Вариант (1) простой (для уяснения) и надежный (сразу защищает от xss). Думаю, что поэтому его часто советуют.

Минус в том, что в базе будет лежать `трактор &quot;Беларусь&quot;` и это нужно учитывать, формируя pdf, экспортируя данные в другую систему и т. п.

В сложной системе мест, где данные попадают в html может быть столько же, сколько мест, где с этим html надо будет бороться.

Вариант (2), где в базе `трактор "Беларусь"` работает хорошо, но требует слишком высокой дисциплины.

Вариант (3), где в базе `трактор "Беларусь"` работает лучше всего, но требует понять изначально больше абстракций.

---

Как посмотреть магию:

```
$string = 'трактор "Беларусь"'; 
echo '<br> 1) '.$string;
echo '<br> 2) '.htmlspecialchars($string);
echo '<br> 3) <input value="'.$string.'">';
echo '<br> 4) <input value="'.htmlspecialchars($string).'">';
```

Вариант (3) поломан. Суть видна, если делать "View Page Source", запускать `curl -v http://...` или `php` из терминала.